# Creating an object in VB.NET behaves differently on different SQL servers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I have following code which is behaving differently on different servers. In the below method if i write this line of code:

```
Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.SelectAll().Where(conditions).Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto(o.FundingYearId.Value, o.DsoId.Value, o.CustomerId.Value, o.CustomerPosition.Value)).ToList()
```

it returns result on one sql instance but does not return result on other sql instance.

However if i replace the above line with the following, it returns result on both sql instances.

```
Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.
        SelectAll().
        Where(conditions).
        Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto() With {.FundingYearId = o.FundingYearId.Value, .DsoId = o.DsoId.Value, .CustomerId = o.CustomerId.Value, .CustomerPosition = o.CustomerPosition.Value}).
        ToList()
```

Could it be because sql server instances have different settings or it's something to do with the code itself?

--Function

```
Private Shared Function GetCustomerPositionsFromPaid(ByVal customerID As Integer, ByVal fundingYearID As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of CustomerPositionFromPaidDto)
    Dim conditions = PredicateBuilder.True(Of vwCustomerPositionInPaid)()
    conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.CustomerId.Equals(customerID))
    conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.FundingYearId.Equals(fundingYearID))
    conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.DsoId.HasValue)

    'Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.SelectAll().Where(conditions).Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto(o.FundingYearId.Value, o.DsoId.Value, o.CustomerId.Value, o.CustomerPosition.Value)).ToList()
    'Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.SelectAll().Where(conditions).Select(Function(o) New With {.FundingYearId = o.FundingYearId.Value, .DsoId = o.DsoId.Value, .CustomerId = o.CustomerId.Value, .CustomerPosition = o.CustomerPosition.Value}).ToList().Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto(o.FundingYearId, o.DsoId, o.CustomerId, o.CustomerPosition)).ToList()
    Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.
        SelectAll().
        Where(conditions).
        Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto() With {.FundingYearId = o.FundingYearId.Value, .DsoId = o.DsoId.Value, .CustomerId = o.CustomerId.Value, .CustomerPosition = o.CustomerPosition.Value}).
        ToList()
    Return customerPositionsFromPaid
End Function
```

--Select All

```
 Public Shared Function [SelectAll](ByVal conditions As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Return [SelectAll]().Where(conditions)
End Function

Public Shared Function [SelectAll]() As IQueryable(Of T)
    Return Table
End Function

Private Shared ReadOnly Property Table() As Table(Of T)
    Get
        Return Context.GetTable(Of T)()
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Have you got the order of your arguments to `CustomerPositionFromPaidDTo` in the right order? In the second example you're setting the properties explicitly but in the first you're relying on getting them in the right order.

Comment: Yes I have please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manage to solve the above by writing the following code. Looks like because customerid and fundingyearid are nullable objects, i had to use .Value attribute but still not sure why the previous code will work on one server and not on the other one.

```
Private Shared Function GetCustomerPositionsFromPaid(ByVal customerID As Integer, ByVal fundingYearID As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of CustomerPositionFromPaidDto)
Dim conditions = PredicateBuilder.True(Of vwCustomerPositionInPaid)()
conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.CustomerId.Equals(customerID.Value))
conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.FundingYearId.Equals(fundingYearID.Value))
conditions = conditions.And(Function(o) o.DsoId.HasValue)


Dim customerPositionsFromPaid = vwCustomerPositionInPaid.
    SelectAll().
    Where(conditions).
    Select(Function(o) New CustomerPositionFromPaidDto() With {.FundingYearId = o.FundingYearId.Value, .DsoId = o.DsoId.Value, .CustomerId = o.CustomerId.Value, .CustomerPosition = o.CustomerPosition.Value}).
    ToList()
Return customerPositionsFromPaid
```

End Function